# Element.querySelector for the element's direct child

Tags: javascript, html

I have some JS constant with HTML element (for example Div). I need to know if the element contains some HTML structure. For example, here is my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <table class="cls1 cls2">
    <tbody class="cls3 cls4">
      <tr class="cls5 cls6">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

I have JS constant with `<div id="container">` element.
For example:

```
const div = document.querySelector('#container');
```

It is just an example. Actually the div doesn't contain "container" id. And I get this element from some function, so I don't know the element's CSS selector.

I need to know, if the element contains this CSS selector: `table.cls1.cls2 > tbody.cls3.cls4 > tr.cls5.cls6 > td` and the `table.cls1.cls2` must be the direct child of the div. It would be great to use something like this:

```
const ok = div.querySelector('> table.cls1.cls2 > tbody.cls3.cls4 > tr.cls5.cls6 > td');
```

But it is not a valid selector (which starts with ">").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) pseudo class to target self and then write selectors for direct children

```
const ok = div.querySelector(':scope > table.cls1.cls2 > tbody.cls3.cls4 > tr.cls5.cls6 > td');
```